# How to use error-channel for catching exception in Spring Integration?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

**What I am trying to do? :** I am new to Spring Integration and already have read many similar questions regarding error handling but I don't understand how to catch exceptions using `error-channel`?

**What I have done so far:**

```
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
@Configuration
public class TcpClientConfig implements ApplicationEventPublisherAware {

  private ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;
  private final ConnectionProperty connectionProperty;

  @Override
  public void setApplicationEventPublisher(ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher) {
    this.applicationEventPublisher = applicationEventPublisher;
  }

  TcpClientConfig(ConnectionProperty connectionProperty) {
    this.connectionProperty = connectionProperty;
  }

  @Bean
  public AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientConnectionFactory() {
    TcpNioClientConnectionFactory tcpNioClientConnectionFactory =
        getTcpNioClientConnectionFactoryOf(
            connectionProperty.getPrimaryHSMServerIpAddress(),
            connectionProperty.getPrimaryHSMServerPort());

    final List<AbstractClientConnectionFactory> fallBackConnections = getFallBackConnections();
    fallBackConnections.add(tcpNioClientConnectionFactory);

    final FailoverClientConnectionFactory failoverClientConnectionFactory =
        new FailoverClientConnectionFactory(fallBackConnections);

    return new CachingClientConnectionFactory(
        failoverClientConnectionFactory, connectionProperty.getConnectionPoolSize());
  }

  @Bean
  DefaultTcpNioSSLConnectionSupport connectionSupport() {

    final DefaultTcpSSLContextSupport defaultTcpSSLContextSupport =
        new DefaultTcpSSLContextSupport(
            connectionProperty.getKeystorePath(),
            connectionProperty.getTrustStorePath(),
            connectionProperty.getKeystorePassword(),
            connectionProperty.getTruststorePassword());

    final String protocol = "TLSv1.2";
    defaultTcpSSLContextSupport.setProtocol(protocol);
    return new DefaultTcpNioSSLConnectionSupport(defaultTcpSSLContextSupport, false);
  }

  @Bean
  public MessageChannel outboundChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
  }



  @Bean
  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "outboundChannel")
  public MessageHandler outboundGateway(AbstractClientConnectionFactory clientConnectionFactory) {
    TcpOutboundGateway tcpOutboundGateway = new TcpOutboundGateway();
    tcpOutboundGateway.setConnectionFactory(clientConnectionFactory);
    return tcpOutboundGateway;
  }
  @Bean
  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "error-channel")
  public void handleError(ErrorMessage em) {
    throw new RuntimeException(String.valueOf(em));
  }

  private List<AbstractClientConnectionFactory> getFallBackConnections() {
    final int size = connectionProperty.getAdditionalHSMServersConfig().size();
    List<AbstractClientConnectionFactory> collector = new ArrayList<>(size);
    for (final Map.Entry<String, Integer> server :
        connectionProperty.getAdditionalHSMServersConfig().entrySet()) {
      collector.add(getTcpNioClientConnectionFactoryOf(server.getKey(), server.getValue()));
    }
    return collector;
  }

  private TcpNioClientConnectionFactory getTcpNioClientConnectionFactoryOf(
      final String ipAddress, final int port) {
    TcpNioClientConnectionFactory tcpNioClientConnectionFactory =
        new TcpNioClientConnectionFactory(ipAddress, port);
    tcpNioClientConnectionFactory.setUsingDirectBuffers(true);
    tcpNioClientConnectionFactory.setDeserializer(new CustomDeserializer());
    tcpNioClientConnectionFactory.setApplicationEventPublisher(applicationEventPublisher);
    tcpNioClientConnectionFactory.setSoKeepAlive(true);
    tcpNioClientConnectionFactory.setConnectTimeout(connectionProperty.getConnectionTimeout());
    tcpNioClientConnectionFactory.setSoTcpNoDelay(true);
    tcpNioClientConnectionFactory.setTcpNioConnectionSupport(connectionSupport());
    return tcpNioClientConnectionFactory;
  }
}
```

Gateway

```
@Component
@MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "outboundChannel",errorChannel ="error-channel" )
public interface TcpClientGateway {
    String send(String message);
}
```

Also currently, I am facing

```
required a bean of type org.springframework.messaging.support.ErrorMessage that could not be found
```

I need some assistance!
Thanking you in advance,

### EDIT

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Service
public class AsyncNonBlockingClient implements Connector {
  TcpClientGateway tcpClientGateway;

  @Override
  public String send(final String payload) {
    return tcpClientGateway.send(payload);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See documentation about messaging annotation:

Your problem is here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/configuration.html#annotations_on_beans

```
  @Bean
  @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "error-channel")
  public void handleError(ErrorMessage em) {
```

This is a plain POJO method, therefore it cannot be marked with a `@Bean`. You use a `@Bean` really for beans to expose. Then you decide if that has to be a `@ServiceActivator` or not. So, just remove `@Bean` from this method and your `error-channel` consumer should be OK.

Comment: thanks a lot for your quick assistance. :)

Yes, my bad, it worked. 

Do you think ServiceActivator is a good option here? As you said "Then you decide if that has to be a @ServiceActivator or not."

Comment: It is: that's a general consumer choice. You go with other, more specific messaging annotation only if you really need that particular pattern. Technically all of them are just extensions of the service activator.

Comment: Hi Artem, is there any way I can verify how many sockets are created? And which IP Address I am currently connected to whether fallback has been used or it is the original one?

Comment: I think you can implement a `TcpConnectionInterceptor` to catch `send()` and `onMessage()` operations happened from that gateway. Or you can just catch a `TcpConnectionOpenEvent` which comes from the `TcpNioClientConnectionFactory`. See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/ip.html#ip-interceptors, https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/ip.html#tcp-events

Comment: Sorry for a silly question Artem, I am facing a critical issue, that a request is receiving a different response that is meant for different request threads during the performance testing using the above configuration.

Are default headers not enough to uniquely identify a particular request or do we need to add enrich headers to uniquely identify a request?

Comment: I think this one deserves its own detailed SO question. See this rule: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask